# A fabulous word for a small wooded area

Tags: single-word-requests

My roommates and I want to name this little "island" on the culdesac that we live on, a sort of nickname.

We aren't looking for something literal, something humorously exaggeratory, like "the sacred grove" or something, but more creative and epic, and no adjective would be better.

...................... [image: tree on an island]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLIzr.jpg

Comment: How about: "Kidney Isle"

Comment: Such an area can be called a *copse*, which might be too literal for you. (SJ Perleman once rendered "Flee! Birnam Wood approaches!" as "Cheese it, the copse!")

Comment: @J.R. So it could be "Langerhans" then (-:

Comment: I would suggest *Verdant*, the club from TV series Arrow. Sounds pretty badass to me. But it's really an adjective so I'll leave it as a comment

Comment: @Jim Mack:  no, the Islets of Langerhans are in the pancreas. Perhaps you were thinking of those lovely tropical atolls in the Adrenal Archipelago.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Well of *course* they're in the pancreas. I wasn't being... what's the word... *literal*. (-:

Comment: the forest of Aragorn!

Answer (score 23):

***Yggdrasil***.

> In Scandinavian mythology, the great tree whose branches and roots extend through the universe. Also *allusively*. *[OED]*

It is from Old Norse *yg(g)drasill*, also *askr yg(g)drasils* lit. ash-tree of Yggdrasil (? < *Yggr* name of Odin + *drasill* horse; but the formation is obscure).<sup>OED</sup>

[image]
<sub>"The Ash Yggdrasil" (1886) by Friedrich Wilhelm Heine</sub>

Comment: Ahh so that's where the name comes from in Warcraft 3....

Comment: *...whose branches and roots extend through the universe* Don't think anything can top that epicness

Comment: *How* on earth is it pronounced?

Comment: **ig**-dra-sil
Or, if you're IPA-literate, /ˈɪg drə sɪl/

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you want to be all hoity-toity about it and pronounce it the _authentic_ way, it’s basically as written: ['yɡːˌdɾasilː].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what's this about me being "hoity-toity"? Excuse me for being momentarily taken aback when I see a "ygg" and wonder about its pronunciation. It won't happen again.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you misread me—it was meant as “or, if you want to be really fancy and poncy and make sure to pronounce it the way the Norsemen did 1300 years ago”, not to imply that you were being hoity-toity!

Answer (score 14):

**Nemetonia**, original term, derived from “[***nemeton***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemeton)”

---

[image]

---

> **A *nemeton* was a sacred space of ancient Celtic religion**. *Nemeta* appear to have been primarily situated in natural areas, and, as they often utilized trees, they are often interpreted as sacred groves. However, other evidence suggests that the word implied a wider variety of ritual spaces, such as shrines and temples. Evidence for *nemeta* consists chiefly of inscriptions and place-names, which occur all across the Celtic world. Toponyms related to the word *nemeton* occur as far west as Galicia, Spain, as far north as Scotland, and as far east as central Turkey. The word is related to the name of the *Nemetes* tribe living by the Rhine between the Palatinate and Lake Constance in what is now Germany, and their goddess ***Nemetona***
>
> Pliny and Lucan wrote that druids did not meet in stone temples or other constructions, but in sacred groves of trees. In his *Pharsalia*, Lucan described such a grove near Massilia in dramatic terms more designed to evoke a shiver of delicious horror among his Roman hearers than meant as proper natural history:
>
> *[N]o bird nested in the nemeton, nor did any animal lurk nearby; the leaves constantly shivered though no breeze stirred. Altars stood in its midst, and the images of the gods. Every tree was stained with sacrificial blood, the very earth groaned, dead yews revived; unconsumed trees were surrounded with flame, and huge serpents twined round the oaks. The people feared to approach the grove, and even the priest would not walk there at midday or midnight lest he should then meet its divine guardian*.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 11):

[***arboretum***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/arboretum), "a sort of museum for trees," might be the sort of hyperbole you're looking for.

Something about latinate words; they sound pompous. "Jeeves! To the arboreteum!  Make haste!"

Answer (score 7):

***Bosk.***

> a small wooded area *[[MW]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bosk)*

And for the *epicness* of the word:

[image]

<sub>Image source: [gatherer.wizards.com](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152557)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Since the "island" would appear from above as a disconnected patch of growth surrounded by a smooth area, I suggest "**The Pubes**" or, "**The Axillary**".

Answer (score 4):

In Tolkien's Sindarin: *Tol Calen,* the green isle, written [like this](http://3rin.gs/tengwar/?q=tol%20calen&font=parmaite&mode=general-use&height=null&language=sindarin) in Tengwar.

Answer (score 4):

How about [**Avalon**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon)?

Derived from the Breton word for apple tree, Avalon was a legendary isle featured in the tales of King Arthur. It was also where Excalibur was forged.

Answer (score 3):

Given the description,"Stickormore" sounds both humorous and outlandish to me. Hope it helps.
As a matter of fact, drop the e at the end and it'll become even mor(e) unique.

Comment: This answer would be improved with a definition and some context for the word, rather than leaving it to us to google to find out what it is. Look at other people's answers for examples.

Comment: Ah, I believe this was a bit of creative wordplay and coined just for Master Hebert's benefit, @dwjohnston.  +1 for the creative approach, Dunnup.

Comment: @dwjohnston I guess it's "sycamore" plus "stick or more" (the latter implying that it's actually small, belying its grandiose-sounding name).

Answer (score 3):

That spot looks like a good candidate for ***Fallback Position Alpha***

...or ***Waypoint B***.

It could in fact become ***The Nexus*** or better yet: **SEKTOR EINZ!** (but cannot be said sitting down)

Answer (score 2):

[**The Least Resort**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hdx6oyBOVj0)

---

[image]

---

*An ironic play on the Eagles "Last Resort," and the solitary tree in the OP's miniature resort.*

> **resort** *noun*: **1**. a place that is a popular destination for vacations or recreation, or which is frequented for a particular purpose. "a seaside *resort*"
>
> **resort** *verb*: **2**. formal go often or in large numbers to.
>   "local authorities have a duty to provide adequate sites for gypsies “residing in or *resorting* to” their areas"
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=resort+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=resort+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.0.33201...........0.yObMv-zxQdw&gws_rd=ssl)

---

> **resort** (*n*.) late 14c., "that to which one has recourse for aid or assistance," from Old French resort "resource, a help, an aid, a remedy," back-formation from *resortir* "to resort," literally "to go out again," from re- "again" (see re-) + *sortir* "go out" (see sortie). Meaning "place people go for recreation" is first recorded 1754. Phrase in the last resort (1670s) translates French *en dernier ressort*, originally of legal appeals.

---

> **resort** (*v*.) c. 1400, "issue; come out again;" mid-15c., "to go to (someone) for aid," from Old French *resortir*, from resort (see resort (*n*.)). Related: Resorted; resorting.
>
> [**etymonline**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=resort&searchmode=nl)

Answer (score 2):

[Ultima Thule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thule)

> The term **ultima Thule** in medieval geographies denotes any distant place located beyond the "borders of the known world"
>
> The Greek explorer Pytheas is the first to have written of Thule, [etc.]

It's epic because that cul de sac is unknown to most people in the world (IOW "beyond borders of the known world"); but for you who know it, once you get there you know you've really arrived.

Answer (score 1):

Something a little more recent, and as far as grandeur is concerned, "epic", from the movie Avatar, the term: **Kelutral**

> Hometrees (Na'vi name: *Kelutral*) are massive trees that can be found throughout Pandora. Many Na'vi clans, such as the Omaticaya and the Tipani make these enormous plants their home. [...]about 150m tall […] The circumference of a **[Hometree](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Hometree)** is great enough to house dozens of clan members. The tree is honeycombed with natural hollows and alcoves in which the Na'vi sleep, eat, weave, dance and celebrate their connection to Eywa

[image](http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Avatar-trees.jpg)

Comment: Excellent suggestion, Mari-Lou.

Comment: @LittleEva you're too kind. It's an Okish suggestion, if they're fans of the movie, but not many people are nowadays.

Comment: I actually did a Google search for "*okish*," thought you were slinging about some arcane Celtic or Yiddish term I was ignorant of - note the sheepish smile. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva  The curse of EL&U  has struck once again. When you start doublechecking slang because you think they are esoteric, you know you've been online too long! :)) I should have really written it as OKish, so blame my measly orthographic skills.

Comment: Do me a "solid" sis, (forgive me, but I'm binge-watching the tv series 'The Wire') check-out my answer - in comments - below this "duplicate" [OP](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256556/is-there-an-umbrella-term-for-fictional-and-non-fictional-works), and get back with me on your thoughts.

Comment: Movies are not considered literature, however.

Comment: Your opinion - should it remain closed?

Comment: @LittleEva deleting off topic comments :))

Answer (score 1):

The Great Forest or maybe Fangorn (but that would be to borrow from LoTR).  Then you could say, "Rosengarth, meet me at the entrance to The Great Forest.."