# Is there an umbrella term for fictional and non-fictional works?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that describes movies, books, poems, plays, and basically anything that is either fiction or non-fiction. "Media" doesn't work because that includes songs and paintings.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: All works are either fictional or non-fictional, so why not "works"?

Comment: I'll remove the downvote if you can provide a context that requires such a word.

Comment: You're going to have to explain more. What is it about movies that makes them included, and what is it about songs and paintings that makes them excluded? What else is included or excluded?

Comment: How about *literature*?

Comment: OP requests a single-word which could act as an “umbrella” term for fictional and non-fictional movies, books, poems and plays, **but rejects the most obvious choice of the noun “media” because “that includes songs and paintings**.” (The bolded text could be considered as differentiating this OP from the previously posed question.)

Comment: Because the primary sense of the noun [song](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/song) is a short piece of music with lyrics, and lyrics are a type of poetry, I must assume it is the musical aspect of song that OP finds unsuitable and, indeed, music is certainly included under media’s umbrella. The OP’s inclusion of “paintings” under that same media umbrella is more tenuous, as paintings are not commonly understood as media, though if by “painting” the OP includes graphic art, then media could be considered to include paintings.

Comment: My attempts to find a single-word “umbrella” term for fictional and non-fictional movies, books, poems and plays, have led to this conclusion: no other single-word is more suitable as an umbrella term for the diverse works of art listed in the OP, than the term **media**. Umbrella terms require a significant degree of inclusivity, if “media” is too inclusive, its meaning can be specified contextually, whereas all other single-word options are insufficiently inclusive to act as “umbrella” terms.

Comment: It occurs to me that all fictional and non-fictional movies, books, poems and plays could be categorized as “**narratives**” (hewing desperately to the single-word requirement) or “**narrative works**.”

Comment: Yes, the umbrella term for this is *umbrella works*.

Answer (score 0):

**texts**   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_linguistics

> A text is an extended structure of syntactic units [i.e. text as
>   super-sentence] such as words, groups, and clauses and textual units
>   that is marked by both coherence among the elements and completion ...
>   [Whereas] A non-text consists of random sequences of linguistic units
>   such as sentences, paragraphs, or sections in any temporal and/or
>   spatial extension. (Werlich, 1976: 23)[3]

I was going to add **script, scripts**; but "Late Middle English (in the sense 'something written'):" 
(from:  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/script )  is way down the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could use 'prose', or 'written works'.

Comment: The OP includes "movies".

Comment: Then I stand corrected.

Comment: ... and poems, too.